# Issue with for each loop in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have posted this in mrexcel but not got a response. That's why I'm posting here.

I'm having two issues with the below code.

1. If the range is containing only one row, like `H12-K12` then it's only run for first cell `I12` & then stop. But it should run till `K15`.
2. If the range is containing multiple rows as `H12-K15`, then it's run till `I15` & after that, it stops. But it should run till `K15`.

What am I doing wrong?

Data.....

[image]

Required output as below.
[Required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiNqw.png)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatPackingList()
    
'    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim xTitleId As String
    xTitleId = "Input box--"
    
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    
    Dim xNum As Integer
    xNum = Application.InputBox("Division num", xTitleId, Type:=1)
    
    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Rng.Value > xNum Then
        
            Dim nThNumber As Double
            nThNumber = Rng.Value / xNum
            
            Dim nThNumberNoDecimil As Single
            nThNumberNoDecimil = nThNumber
            
            'to remove decimil data
            Dim nThNumberNoDecInt As Integer
            nThNumberNoDecInt = CInt(Fix(nThNumberNoDecimil))
            
            Dim totalValue As Integer
            totalValue = nThNumberNoDecInt * xNum
            
            Dim balanceValue As Integer
            balanceValue = Rng.Value - totalValue
            
            Rng.Value = xNum
            Rng.EntireRow.Copy
            
            Dim cUrrentCellCol As Integer
            cUrrentCellCol = Range(Rng.Offset(0, 0), Rng.Offset(0, 0)).Column
            Dim cUrrentCellRow As Integer
            cUrrentCellRow = Range(Rng.Offset(0, 0), Rng.Offset(0, 0)).Row
            
            'coPyRowNThTime
            '----------------------
            If balanceValue > 0 Then
                Dim coPyRowNThTime As Integer
                coPyRowNThTime = 2
                Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(coPyRowNThTime, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1, 0)).Value = balanceValue
                Range(Rng.Offset(2, 0), Rng.Offset(2, 0)).ClearContents
                'Ctn no at column T
                Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 20).Value = nThNumberNoDecInt
                Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 20).Offset(1, 0).Value = 1
                
                If cUrrentCellCol = 8 Then
                
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 9), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 9).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                ElseIf cUrrentCellCol = 19 Then
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 18)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 18).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                    
                Else
                    Dim leftColNumber As Integer
                    leftColNumber = cUrrentCellCol - 1
                    Dim rightColNumber As Integer
                    rightColNumber = cUrrentCellCol + 1
                    
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, leftColNumber)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, leftColNumber).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, rightColNumber), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, rightColNumber).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                    
                End If
                    'delete emptye row in H-S column, if qty is nothing
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(2, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(2, 0))) = 0 Then
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(2, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 18).Offset(2, 0)).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                    
            Else
                coPyRowNThTime = 1
                Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(coPyRowNThTime, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                
                'Ctn no at column T
                Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 20).Value = nThNumberNoDecInt
                
                If cUrrentCellCol = 8 Then
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 9), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19)).ClearContents
                
                ElseIf cUrrentCellCol = 19 Then
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 18)).ClearContents
                
                Else
                    leftColNumber = cUrrentCellCol - 1
                    rightColNumber = cUrrentCellCol + 1
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, leftColNumber)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, rightColNumber), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19)).ClearContents
                
                End If
                
                'delete emptye row in H-S column, if qty is nothing
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(1, 0))) = 0 Then
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 18).Offset(1, 0)).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                
            End If
        '---------------------
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Formatted code is very helpful. 2. What's the purpose of `On Error Resume Next` when you don't catch any errors, nor return the error catching back to normal. (I editted your code and removed as there is no reason to have it). 3. Your ranges are not qualified. Suggest reviewing your code and update. Look at RubberDuck or MZ-Tools to help with the updates.

Comment: The root reason why your code "stops" is that on the first iteration through the loop, when processining cell `I12`, the line `Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, rightColNumber), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19)).ClearContents` clears cells `J12:K12` .  So when the For loop goes to the next iteration,  `Rng` will refer to `J12` and `If Rng.Value > xNum Then` will be False.  It's not at all clear what you are trying to do here, so I won't guess at possible fixes.  Couple of basics, though: get rid of `On Error Resumre Next` and since you are inserting rows, loop fro bottom to top of your range of rows.

Comment: Even after get ride of On Error Resume, it's acting the same. Here is my file with the code. [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXE6pPDLZF4CG9q2dGzoc8gE1q-D0Q2u/view)

Comment: @MehidyHassan of course it acts the same - did you not understand the rest of my comment?

Comment: BTW there is never a need to `.Copy` and `.Paste` as you can assign values directly. Also, be wary of naked `Cells()` calls that imply `ActiveSheet`. Better be safe and specify exactly on what sheet or range `.Cells()` works with. A lot of the code can be simplified with calls to `Range.Resize()` instead of `Range(Cells(),Cells())`. For example `Range("A2").Resize(4,10)` returns a reference to `A2:J5`, starting from `A2` use 4 rows and 10 columns under and to the right for the reference.

Comment: to the editors: Deleting `On Error Resume Next` andcorrect indenting would form part of a good _Answer_ to the Q, not an edit

Comment: @MehidyHassan you've shown us what you data looks like _before_ the code runs and told us the code "stops" after a certain point.  I've told you _why_ that happens.  You've not shown us what you _want_ your data to look like after the code runs.  Please update your Q with the result of what you want your code to do (createit manualy if you have to).  Until you do that your Q is unanswerable, and should be closed.

Comment: @chrisneilsen added the picture of the required output as you advise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting my required result with the below code, reveres loop bottom to top.

```
Sub CreatPackingListReverse()
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range, t As String
    
    Dim xTitleId As String
    xTitleId = "Input box--"
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, Type:=8)
      t = rng.Address
    
    Dim xNum As Integer
    xNum = Application.InputBox("Division num", xTitleId, Type:=1)
    
    For i = Range(t).Cells.Count To 1 Step -1

 If rng.Item(i).Value > xNum Then
        
            Dim nThNumber As Double
            nThNumber = rng.Item(i).Value / xNum
            
            Dim nThNumberNoDecimil As Single
            nThNumberNoDecimil = nThNumber
            
            'to remove decimil data
            Dim nThNumberNoDecInt As Integer
            nThNumberNoDecInt = CInt(Fix(nThNumberNoDecimil))
            
            Dim totalValue As Integer
            totalValue = nThNumberNoDecInt * xNum
            
            Dim balanceValue As Integer
            balanceValue = rng.Item(i).Value - totalValue
            
            rng.Item(i).Value = xNum
            rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Copy
            
            Dim cUrrentCellCol As Integer
            cUrrentCellCol = rng.Item(i).Column
            Dim cUrrentCellRow As Integer
            cUrrentCellRow = rng.Item(i).Row
            
            'coPyRowNThTime
            '----------------------


If balanceValue > 0 Then
                Dim coPyRowNThTime As Integer
                coPyRowNThTime = 2
                Range(rng.Item(i).Offset(1, 0), rng.Item(i).Offset(coPyRowNThTime, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                rng.Item(i).Offset(2, 0).Value = balanceValue
                rng.Item(i).ClearContents
                'Ctn no at column T
                Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 20).Offset(1, 0).Value = nThNumberNoDecInt
                Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 20).Offset(2, 0).Value = 1
                
                If cUrrentCellCol = 8 Then
                
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 9).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 9).Offset(2, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(2, 0)).ClearContents

                ElseIf cUrrentCellCol = 19 Then
                     Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 18).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                     Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(2, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 18).Offset(2, 0)).ClearContents
                    
                Else
                    Dim leftColNumber As Integer
                    leftColNumber = cUrrentCellCol - 1
                    Dim rightColNumber As Integer
                    rightColNumber = cUrrentCellCol + 1
                    
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, leftColNumber).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(2, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, leftColNumber).Offset(2, 0)).ClearContents
                    
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, rightColNumber).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                    Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, rightColNumber).Offset(2, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(2, 0)).ClearContents
                    
                End If
                    'delete emptye row in H-S column, if qty is nothing
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19))) = 0 Then
                    'Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19)).EntireRow.Delete
                    rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                    
            Else
                coPyRowNThTime = 1
                Range(rng.Item(i).Offset(1, 0), rng.Item(i).Offset(coPyRowNThTime, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                rng.Item(i).ClearContents
                
                'Ctn no at column T
                Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 20).Offset(1, 0).Value = nThNumberNoDecInt
                
                If cUrrentCellCol = 8 Then
                 Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 9).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents

                ElseIf cUrrentCellCol = 19 Then
                Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 18).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                
                Else
                    leftColNumber = cUrrentCellCol - 1
                    rightColNumber = cUrrentCellCol + 1
                Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, leftColNumber).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, rightColNumber).Offset(1, 0), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19).Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
                End If
                
                'delete emptye row in H-S column, if qty is nothing
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19))) = 0 Then
                    'Range(Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 8), Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 19)).EntireRow.Delete
                    rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                
            End If

'---------------------
Else
cUrrentCellRow = rng.Item(i).Row
rng.Item(i).Value = rng.Item(i).Value
Cells(cUrrentCellRow, 20).Value = 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```